# Jquery Mobile document.ready not being called from view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I am not able to get document.ready event or attach button click event.
What am i missing here?

This is how my view looks like:

```
@section script
{
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document.ready(function(){

    alert('Hello');

});

        $('#btnGo').bind('click', function () {
            alert('User clicked button');
        });

    </script>
}
<input type="text" id="txtStop" />
<input type="button" id="btnGo" value="Get Schedule" />
```

This is how my layout file looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
@RenderSection("script")
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">@RenderBody()</div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not declaring the document.ready properly

Currently it's 
 `$(document.ready(function(){`

It either needs to be

```
$(function(){
    alert('Document is ready!');
     $('#btnGo').bind('click', function () {
        alert('User clicked button');
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){ .... });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in your script (incorrect bracing and parens).  Change it to this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('Hello');
    $('#btnGo').bind('click', function () {
        alert('User clicked button');
    });
});
</script>
```

There would have been javascript errors showing in the error console to show you this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't even need the document ready event.  Just place the bind event somewhere after the button exists on the page.  This is universal, regardless of your use of jquery mobile or not, you can bind an event handler to an object as soon as it exists within the DOM. Depending on how much you're loading on the page and how long it takes, it might be a higher performance way of doing things.

```
<head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <a href="#linkToWhatever" id="btnGo" data-role="button">click me</a>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#btnGo').bind('click', function () {
            alert('User clicked button');
        });
    </script>
</body>
```